# Firebase Authentication returns NULL for getCurrentUser() even though there's a user in Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments

When a user in a registration fragment enters a `username`, `email`, and `password` he is forwarded to a verification fragment where I sent him email verification and he stays on that screen until he clicks the link from the email, after that he's forwarded to profile fragment.

While the user is on the verification fragment, he can go back to the registration fragment before clicking the link from the email I sent. In that case, I call a function from onStart() to delete his data from the Firebase:

```
private fun deleteUnverifiedAccount() {
        val firebaseAuthentication = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        if (firebaseAuthentication.currentUser == null) {
            shortToast("empty")
        }
        if (firebaseAuthentication.currentUser != null) {
            if (!firebaseAuthentication.currentUser.isEmailVerified) {
                val user = firebaseAuthentication.currentUser
                user.delete()
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        shortToast("deleted")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the problem:

1. This function successfully deletes the user from Firebase Authentication
2. But when the user tries to register the second time, his data is again being saved to Firebase Authentication.
3. And if at the moment he goes back again to the registration fragment without verifying his email then his data is not deleted from Firebase Authentication.
4. And when the `deleteUnverifiedAccount()` function is called it says that `currentUser == null` even though he is clearly not null in Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i did not try to delete any user from firebase but i have just searched something and i find this link https://www.javatpoint.com/firebase-realtime-database-update-and-delete this link will help you because i think problem of your code you try to delete your user but not user's data.
your syntax will be like this

```
myFirebase.child(current user's id).remove value
```

can you try this before user.delete() i hope it works